# Realm : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException rowIndex > available rows: 0 > 0

Tags: android

I try to read mydata with Realm in android calling two database like this

```
Realm myRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<ChapterRealm> rsChap = myRealm.where(ChapterRealm.class)
            .equalTo("subj_id",subj_id)
            .equalTo("name",holder.main_title.toString())
            .findAll();

    RealmResults<QuestionRealm> rsQues = myRealm.where(QuestionRealm.class)
            .equalTo("chapter_id",rsChap.get(position).getId())
            .findAll();
```

and it shows below error at RealmResults

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: rowIndex > available rows: 0 > 0
```

Help me to solve this please.

Comment: does `rsChap` have actually any rows?

Comment: rsChap has. But rsQues doesn't. I am checking if rsQues data already exists or not.